# Check if Google Sheets Cell is Edited for a Month

Tags: javascript, automation, google-apps

I have a Google Sheet which has a staff list and a particular column needs to be updated by all the staff members every month. I want to write a google script which will check if the staff have edited their cell or not and automatically email them if they have not. I figured out how to email them through the script and how to automatically get the current user. Given the cell I need to check, how can I check if it has been edited in the past 30 days ?

Any help is much appreciated ! Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if you can check modification dates on particular cells - just the entire document. Sounds like an interesting problem - what have you tried or found in your research efforts? The Google Drive API may be a place to start.

Answer (score 0):

that information is not kept per cell and is not part of the api.

there are a few ways to do it. one way, (assuming new rows are not inserted or removed) is to have a recurring time trigger (say every 1 day or longer) that checks which rows have changed by comparing it with data on a hidden and protected sheet.

store the change status in an extra column in your protected sheet. update your protected copy with the latest values and email those that are over 1 month late.